# setTextAppearance doesn't affect text content

Tags: android, textview, android-styles

Well, I have a problem with `setTextAppearance` when apply a style to the `TextView` object at runtime.

I defined this in the layout:

```
<TextView style="@style/Proximity_Far" android:id="@+id/tvNearFar" />
```

In `/res/values/styles.xml` I defined this:

```
<style name="Proximity">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
<style name="Proximity_Near" parent="Proximity">
    <item name="android:textSize">140dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#ff00ff05</item>
    <item name="android:text">Near!</item>
</style>
<style name="Proximity_Far" parent="Proximity">
    <item name="android:textSize">70dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffff0079</item>
    <item name="android:text">Far!</item>
</style>
```

You can see that I have set the text in each style `Proximity_Near` and `Proximity_Far`.
So then I call the function `setTextAppearance` in order to change style and also the display text of  `tvNearFar` on the view:

```
tvNearFar.setTextAppearance(getApplicationContext(), R.style.Proximity_Near);
```

But this only affects on the text style, the text content stays unchanged.
Anyone can explain me about this? I'm working on Android Studio, and I can see that change when I change the style id in layout file at design time, but it doesn't work at runtime.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Android developer [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextAppearance%28android.content.Context,%20int%29):

> public void setTextAppearance (Context context, int resid)
>
> Sets the text color, size, style, hint color, and highlight color from the specified TextAppearance resource.

It's not supposed to change the String. "Style" in this case means textStyle bold/normal/italic.

You'll have to set the String separately to achieve what you wanted.

Comment: This makes me a bit disappointed since in Html and CSS I can use `:after` pseudo class comes with `content` property to change the content inside an item. :(

Comment: you will be even more disappointed when you discover that there is no css-style way to add borders, rounded corners or dropshadows